# Вызвать PHP функцию с помощью ссылки <a>

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Нужно вызвать такую функцию через POST:

```
if (isset($_POST['exit'])) {
    unset($_COOKIE['token']);
    setcookie('token', null, -1);
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Подскажите, как лучше это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть пару вариантов:

1. С помощью формы:

   ```
   <form action="action.php" method="POST">
       <input type="hidden" name="exit" value="1" />
       <a class="submit" href="#">Exit</a>
   </form>

   <script>
       $('form .submit').click(function () {
           $(this).parents('form').submit();
       });
   </script>
   ```
2. С помощью метода `$.post()` библиотеки jQuery:

   ```
   <a class="redirectable" href="action.php?exit=1">Exit</a>

   <script>
       $('.redirectable').click(function () {
           $.post($(this).attr('href'))
               .success(function (data) {
                   if (data && data.result === 'ok')
                       window.location.href = data.location;
               });
       });
   </script>
   // или
   <a id="exit" href="action.php">Exit</a>

   <script>
       $('#exit').click(function () {
           $.post($(this).attr('href'), { exit: 1 })
               .success(function (data) {
                   if (data && data.result === 'ok')
                           window.location.href = data.location;
               });
       });
   </script>
   ```

   PHP-файл при этом прийдется подправить, так как ajax-ом невозможно перехватить редиректы:

   ```
   if (isset($_POST['exit'])) {
       unset($_COOKIE['token']);
       setcookie('token', null, -1);
       die(json_encode(array('result' => 'ok', 'location' => '/index.php')));
   }
   ```